# How to get my site verified in Google Webmaster Tools(Search Console)?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 302-redirect

One of my client site's home page is getting redirected to an internal page so how will it create any problem in getting it verified from Google Webmaster Tools? Moreover he has used 302 redirect so should I get it changed to 301 redirect?

Comment: I think there is insufficient information in this question. I am unsure of the actual problem you are having. Have you attempted in getting this site verified in Google webmaster and it has failed or are you just asking if the redirects would cause any issues?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different verification methods you could do in order to get your site verified in Google Webmasters tools which Google lists [Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en#verification_details).

If you are worried about issues due to the structure of your site you could verify via a DNS record.

Comment: Yeah I always use DNS to verify domains as well. Works well and doesn't have any effect on the site itself.